# Certification and Provisioning of existing app

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, apple-developer

I'm quite new in this area so please bear with me.

I've been assigned by a client to do a complete re-write for an old **existing** app of his.

**So, he invited me as the role of "developer" in his itunesconnect account but not yet in his Apple Developer account.**

Then when I asked him to invite me as a "member" in his Apple Developer account he said that **he doesn't have the "People" submenu on his dashboard**, and yet he sent me some .provisioningmobile files which I did add them to my Xcode, so I can choose one of them on my Signing(Debug) and Signing(Release) option in my New Project properties settings. ( Automatically manage signing is unchecked)

If using that files, Xcode still complains that : 'No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "xxxxxxxxx" with a private key was found'

When I click manage certificates, Xcode said that "None of your accounts are a member of 'xxxxxxxxxx' ( the team ID )

So what should I do to resolve this issue??

What kind of permission/certificate should I request to my client?

And how to get him to invite me as a team member of the said "xxxxxxxx" team ID, **is it possible for another way if he really can't add me as a "member" of his team?**

I did my previous tasks of iOS development by getting invited as a team member on my previous teams, so I have zero experience in resolving this.

Please kindly help me to enlight this matter from what should I do or what should I ask my client do, since He's not really experienced as well.

Thank you before to anyone that kindly giving out any opinions regarding this matter.

Comment: Not, Because you have also login in Xcode account with Apple ID.

Comment: @KiritModi can you please elaborate more? I don't understand that which point that you're answered to.

Comment: Do you want to build .ipa file for development or production? If production yes, then ask for production provisioning profile along with .p12 file and If it is for development then ask for development provisioning profile along with .p12 file.

Comment: @YogeshRaut currently i've been sent development,Ad-Hoc, and App Store mobileprovisioning files without any kind of .p12 files . I want to build for both development and production. What should I ask him ?

Comment: @AgungPPutra :- You can ask client with provisioning profile of development, production, and any ad_hoc profile, along with .p12 file, so you can build .ipa file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provisioning profile is only part of the code signing equation.  A provisioning profile is set up to build a particular app id (or a wildcard app ID) using one or more certificate.  You are missing the certificate (and private key) for the provisioning profile you were sent.

Unfortunately, if the client didn't know they needed to send you the certificate and private key, I would imagine that they probably did not save it somewhere that they can send it to you.  I would ask for it, but be prepared for them to respond that they don't have it. If they aren't sure, see if they still have the Mac that was used to originally build the app. If so, they can export the cert and key from the Keychain app on that Mac.

If they don't have it, you should ask them to generate a new certificate, then generate a new provisioning profile tied to the new cert, and send you the new profile, cert, and private key.

Comment: thank you for your explanation, yea it seems so. I will try to follow up to my client.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete your AppleID ,and than add a new one， download manual profiles.

[image]